# Parquet file giving exception : The UTC offset of local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(("2014-10-06"), ("2014-10-07"), ("2014-10-08"), ("2014-10-09"), ("2014-10-10")).toDF("DATE")
df.printSchema()

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, to_date}
val df2 = df.withColumn("DATE", to_date(col("DATE"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df2.printSchema()

df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("C:\\TEMP\\")
```

---

```
root
 |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- DATE: date (nullable = true)
```

In code i able to convert DATE column from string to date type but when the output parquet file is giving following error while opening:

Parquet.ParquetException: fatal error reading column 'DATE'
System.ArgumentException: The UTC Offset of the  local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce this-

> Tried writing and reading the same

```scala
  val df1 = Seq(("2014-10-06"), ("2014-10-07"), ("2014-10-08"), ("2014-10-09"), ("2014-10-10")).toDF("DATE")
    df1.printSchema()

    /**
      * root
      * |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
      */
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, to_date}
    val df2 = df1.withColumn("DATE", to_date(col("DATE"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
    df2.printSchema()

    /**
      * root
      * |-- DATE: date (nullable = true)
      */

    df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("/Users/sokale/models/stack")

    spark.read.parquet("/Users/sokale/models/stack").show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+
      * |DATE      |
      * +----------+
      * |2014-10-08|
      * |2014-10-09|
      * |2014-10-10|
      * |2014-10-06|
      * |2014-10-07|
      * +----------+
      */
```

Comment: I also able to read this as dataframe  from read.parquet but when i am trying to open it in Parquet Viewer application it gives error

Comment: can you try changing the name of column to `date_column`? like `val df2 = df1.withColumn("date_column", to_date(col("DATE"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))`. Save `df2` and try reading the `part` file via application. May be application is using `DATE` in some different sense